# Variables de entorno Tomcat

Tags: angular, http, tomcat, angular9, spa

Estoy en un proyecto en el cual necesito tener varias variables de entorno en Angular, pero no puedo solicitar que sean en varias compilaciones (-ng build --prod, -ng build --des...), si no crear solo un -ng build de Angular, pero que pueda recoger del servidor de Tomcat las variables de entorno que tenga definidas en el mismo, para que a la hora de tener que modificarse, solo haya que habilitar dichas variables en Tomcat.

He estado buscando, pero lo único que encuentro es definir las variables de entorno en "environment.ts", pero me solicitan que no puede estar en el código fuente, si no que las recoja del servidor (como bien se puede hacer en Java).

¿Me podríais ayudar o pasar algún enlace donde explique esto, o es imposible comunicar las variables de entorno de un servidor Tomcat con Angular?

Gracias.

Comment: No sé si tienes claro lo que es Tomcat: lo que se te está pidiendo en que haya un servicio Java al que le pidas por AJAX las variables de entorno que se hayan definido (en un fichero, en una base de datos...). Eso significa implementar en backend el servicio y luego llamarlo desde tu SPA

Comment: En cualquier caso, te recomiendo leer [ask] y el [tour] de bienvenida para obtener una primera medalla :)

Comment: Hola Pablo, gracias por tu explicación, pero lo que me solicitan es una comunicación directa entre tomcat-angular, sin tener que pasar por Java, de ahí mi confusión.

Gracias por la recomendación para la primera medalla :D

Comment: En ese caso lo que necesitas es poner un JSON en los assets de tu aplicación